# Find all matching datatributes

Tags: jquery

So consider the following `div`:

```
<div class="manage-wrapper d-flex py-5 eachJob hide-on-check" data-location="" data-city="city" data-province="province" data-position="something">
  <p>Content Here</p>
</div>
```

I tried the following in the console:

```
$('[data-location=""] [data-city="city"] [data-province="province"] [data-positon="something"]');
```

But I got nothing back in the console (When I expected one `div`). I am trying to match on this `div`, or any `div`, that matches all of these `data-` attributes.

Why?

To hide any that don't exactly match these data-attributes.

Ideas?

Comment: Should `data-positon` be `data-position`? Also, remove the spaces between the attribute selectors.

Comment: @trincot no, should be nothing between them. Comma would be only one of the attributes, not all.

Comment: And they want AND, not OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces between your attribute selectors:

```js
console.log($('[data-location=""][data-city="city"][data-province="province"][data-position="something"]').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="manage-wrapper  d-flex py-5 eachJob hide-on-check" 
  data-location="" 
  data-city="city" 
  data-province="province" 
  data-position="something">

    <p>Content Here</p>

</div>
```

Spaces between selectors denote *child* elements. With spaced attribute selectors like in your question, that would indicate that the root element must have the first attribute (`[data-location=""]`), and then each descendant after that must also have the corresponding attribute. That is to say, the child would be `[data-city="city"]` and the grandchild would be `[data-province="province"]`.

Note that you also have `data-positon`, though this won't affect the selection.